# Accessing Method of MainActivity from Xaml.cs file

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Following problem: In my Xamarin:Forms App I need to call a method to start a broadcast message which is located in my MainActivity. The OnButtonClicked() Method is in my xaml.cs file

My MainActivity Code

```
public class MainActivity : 
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    public static MainActivity MainActivityInstance { get; private set; }
    Receiver rec;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

        MainActivityInstance = this;
        rec = new Receiver();
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] 
        permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, 
        grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    public void sendBroadcastMessage()
    {
        if (rec != null)
        {
            SendBroadcast(new Intent("com.xamarin.example.TEST"));
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        RegisterReceiver(rec, new IntentFilter("com.xamarin.example.TEST"));
        // Code omitted for clarity
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        UnregisterReceiver(rec);
        // Code omitted for clarity
        base.OnPause();
    }

}
```

}

My BroadcastReceiver:

```
namespace AppCommunication.Droid
{
[BroadcastReceiver]
public class Receiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(context, "Received intent!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}
```

}

My XAML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="AppCommunication.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Button Text="START"
         Clicked="OnStartButtonClicked">
        </Button>
    </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage>
```

xaml.cs File

```
namespace AppCommunication
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnStartButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

}

I need to call the SendBroadcast() method from the MainActivity in the OnStartButtonClicked method of my xaml.cs file.
As you can see in the code of the MainActivity I already tried it with a static MainActivity object but even so the MainActivity is not visible in the xaml.cs file.
Whats wromg. Please help :-(

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to call Android code from the Forms project directly. In this case, I would use the built in DependencyService.

Introduction to DependencyService: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Example:
In your Forms project, create an interface declaring what your platform-specific classes should do:

```
namespace AppCommunication
{
    public interface IBroadcastService
    {
        void SendBroadcast();
    }
}
```

In your Android project, consume the interface and **register the Dependency** with DependencyService:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(BroadcastService))]
namespace AppCommunication.Droid
{
    public class BroadcastService: IBroadcastService
    {
        public void SendBroadcast()
        {
             //Add broadcast sending logic
        }
    }
}
```

You can now call the SendBroadcast method like this:

```
namespace AppCommunication
{
     public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
     {
            
         public MainPage()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
         }
        
         private void OnStartButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<IBroadcastService>().SendBroadcast();
         }
    }
}
```